# Python Wlan Manager

Tags: python, linux, wifi

Is there a way in python to check whether a Wlan router is accessible?

Something like I give as input the *SSID* and the *password* and get as response if it has worked or not?

Comment: Did a Google search reveal any options?

Comment: Actually there is a way, but I think there must be a better one.
You can manipulate the /etc/network/interfaces file with python and restart the wifi and look whether you can connect to the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [wireless library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wireless/0.3.0).

```
from wireless import Wireless
wireless = Wireless()
wireless.connect(ssid='ssid', password='password')
```

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you.